# cms detect links spelling and code mistakes

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, joomla

Not sure if this is the correct forum to post this question, but does anyone know if a website cms system exists which automatically detects and reports spelling mistakes, broken links, coding errors etc etc.

When I say cms, I mean something like joomla, drupal etc.

If they don't have those capabilities built in, is it possible to get a cms system and find addons which add those capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already tagged the question 'drupal', so I feel I can point you toward Drupal's [spelling checker module](http://drupal.org/project/spellcheck) and [link checker module](http://drupal.org/project/linkchecker).

But I suspect other CMS systems also have perfectly good modules for similar functionality.

Comment: Are both these modules full site scanners?  i.e. do they do a full site scan, then report all the problems in some sort of list form?  Couldn't tell from the links you posted.

Comment: @oshirowanen - with regard to the link checker, yes, it says on the page that it runs a periodic check to make sure all links on the site are working. The spell-check module, I'm not so sure about.